# Printing a matched pattern and its next string using re in python3

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to read a pdf file which is sample invoice and I am trying to fetch some sample details from the pdf like Company Name, Invoice no, GST no, Quantity of Materials etc. For this, first of all I am using PyPDF2 to get the data in the text format and then I have used NLTK toolkit to tokenize the text and remove special characters. The problem is I am not able to print 'Invoice No' and its next string containing the Invoice num. Here is the code below. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import json
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open(path, 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
page_content
```

Below is the output I am getting after extracting text from pdf file

```
"Bank Details :\nBank Name\n:  Hdfc bank\nAccount No\n:  50200004915008\nAccount Name\n:  GNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nIFSC\n:  \nSr. \nNo.\nItem No.\nHSN Code\nArticle Code \nDescription\nColor\nTax %\nQuantity\nUnit Rate\nAmount\n1\nQCNBAG0035\n9\n84715000\nRefurbished DELL LATITUDE \nE7470 (CORE I7 6TH \nGEN/8GB/512GB \nSSD/WEBCAM/14'' TOUCH/WIN-\n10 HOME)\n18\n1\n28,813.56\n28,813.56\nOrder # \nQty Sum\n1\nTotal\n28,813.56\nDiscount Amount\n0\nCGST\n9%\n2593.22\nSGST\n9%\n2593.22\nNet Total\n34,000.00\nAmount in Words: ********* THIRTY FOUR THOUSAND RUPEES AND ZERO  PAISA ONLY \nBill To :\nShip To \nInvoice No.\n: PSIGHT1920000164\nEB Ghatkopar Store\nGMONEY PRIVATE LIMITED\nInvoice Date\n: 21/02/2020\nShop no.7, Raj Hans Helix 3, Shreyas \nCinema,\n1019, C WING, 215 ATRIUM\nPortal Order Id\n: \nLBS Road, Ghatkopar West\nNEXT TO COURTYARD MARRIOT, A.K.ROAD\nCust SA Code\n: \nMumbai\nANDHERI EAST, MUMBAI-400093\nCust Order No.\n: GMONEY PRIVATE \nLIMITED\nPlace of Supply: Maharashtra 400086\nMumbai  - 400093\nShipment Mode\n: \nState Code : 27\nState Code : \nStock Room\n: GHT-STR\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nG.S.T. No. : 27AAICG0467G1Z\nPayment Term\n: \nAWB\nPayment Due\n: 2/21/2020\nPartner Name\nShip to Contact\n: Yash\nTerms & Conditions :\n\nPayment by way of cheque/draft shall be in the name of company only. NEFT/RTGS favouring above bank details.Interest @24%per annum shall be \nlevied for delayed payment.\n\nBank charges of Rs.500/- plus GST per cheque shall be charged in case of dishonour of the cheque.\n\nThe courts at Mumbai only shall have the jurisdiction to entertain any dispute between the parties.\n\nWhether Tax is payable on Reverse Charge basis : No\nPage  1  of  1\nRegd Off. : Unit No. 415, Hubtown Solaris,N. S. Phadke Marg, Andheri East, Mumbai-400069\nTel No.: 022-61445600 TO 615 Fax No.: \nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nAuthorised Signatory\nTAX INVOICE\nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nRAJHANS, HELIX-3, L.B.S  ROAD\nGHATKOPAR WEST, MUMBAI\nMumbai  Maharashtra - 400086\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nState Code : 27\n"
```

After using NLTK, the text is cleaned below is the output:

```
import nltk
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(page_content)
import string
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
stripped = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
print(stripped)

['Bank', 'Details', '', 'Bank', 'Name', '', 'Hdfc', 'bank', 'Account', 'No', '', '50200004915008', 'Account', 'Name', '', 'GNG', 'Electronics', 'Pvt', 'Ltd', 'IFSC', '', 'Sr', 'No', '', 'Item', 'No', '', 'HSN', 'Code', 'Article', 'Code', 'Description', 'Color', 'Tax', '', 'Quantity', 'Unit', 'Rate', 'Amount', '1', 'QCNBAG0035', '9', '84715000', 'Refurbished', 'DELL', 'LATITUDE', 'E7470', '', 'CORE', 'I7', '6TH', 'GEN8GB512GB', 'SSDWEBCAM14', '', 'TOUCHWIN', '10', 'HOME', '', '18', '1', '2881356', '2881356', 'Order', '', 'Qty', 'Sum', '1', 'Total', '2881356', 'Discount', 'Amount', '0', 'CGST', '9', '', '259322', 'SGST', '9', '', '259322', 'Net', 'Total', '3400000', 'Amount', 'in', 'Words', '', '', 'THIRTY', 'FOUR', 'THOUSAND', 'RUPEES', 'AND', 'ZERO', 'PAISA', 'ONLY', 'Bill', 'To', '', 'Ship', 'To', 'Invoice', 'No', '', '', 'PSIGHT1920000164', 'EB', 'Ghatkopar', 'Store', 'GMONEY', 'PRIVATE', 'LIMITED', 'Invoice', 'Date', '', '21022020', 'Shop', 'no7', '', 'Raj', 'Hans', 'Helix', '3', '', 'Shreyas', 'Cinema', '', '1019', '', 'C', 'WING', '', '215', 'ATRIUM', 'Portal', 'Order', 'Id', '', 'LBS', 'Road', '', 'Ghatkopar', 'West', 'NEXT', 'TO', 'COURTYARD', 'MARRIOT', '', 'AKROAD', 'Cust', 'SA', 'Code', '', 'Mumbai', 'ANDHERI', 'EAST', '', 'MUMBAI400093', 'Cust', 'Order', 'No', '', '', 'GMONEY', 'PRIVATE', 'LIMITED', 'Place', 'of', 'Supply', '', 'Maharashtra', '400086', 'Mumbai', '', '400093', 'Shipment', 'Mode', '', 'State', 'Code', '', '27', 'State', 'Code', '', 'Stock', 'Room', '', 'GHTSTR', 'GST', '', 'No', '', '', '27AADCG6133E1ZV', 'GST', '', 'No', '', '', '27AAICG0467G1Z', 'Payment', 'Term', '', 'AWB', 'Payment', 'Due', '', '2212020', 'Partner', 'Name', 'Ship', 'to', 'Contact', '', 'Yash', 'Terms', '', 'Conditions', '', 'Payment', 'by', 'way', 'of', 'chequedraft', 'shall', 'be', 'in', 'the', 'name', 'of', 'company', 'only', '', 'NEFTRTGS', 'favouring', 'above', 'bank', 'detailsInterest', '', '24', '', 'per', 'annum', 'shall', 'be', 'levied', 'for', 'delayed', 'payment', '', 'Bank', 'charges', 'of', 'Rs500', 'plus', 'GST', 'per', 'cheque', 'shall', 'be', 'charged', 'in', 'case', 'of', 'dishonour', 'of', 'the', 'cheque', '', 'The', 'courts', 'at', 'Mumbai', 'only', 'shall', 'have', 'the', 'jurisdiction', 'to', 'entertain', 'any', 'dispute', 'between', 'the', 'parties', '', 'Whether', 'Tax', 'is', 'payable', 'on', 'Reverse', 'Charge', 'basis', '', 'No', 'Page', '1', 'of', '1', 'Regd', 'Off', '', '', 'Unit', 'No', '', '415', '', 'Hubtown', 'Solaris', '', 'N', '', 'S', 'Phadke', 'Marg', '', 'Andheri', 'East', '', 'Mumbai400069', 'Tel', 'No', '', '', '02261445600', 'TO', '615', 'Fax', 'No', '', '', 'GNG', 'Electronics', 'Pvt', 'Ltd', 'Authorised', 'Signatory', 'TAX', 'INVOICE', 'GNG', 'Electronics', 'Pvt', 'Ltd', 'RAJHANS', '', 'HELIX3', '', 'LBS', 'ROAD', 'GHATKOPAR', 'WEST', '', 'MUMBAI', 'Mumbai', 'Maharashtra', '', '400086', 'GST', '', 'No', '', '', '27AADCG6133E1ZV', 'State', 'Code', '', '27']
```

I am using below code to search string starting with I as in Invoice and G as in GST.

```
patterns = ['Invoice No', 'GST No']

z = re.findall("[IG]\w+", element)
print(z)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you need to find items starting with some letters? `[x for x in patterns if x.startswith("I") or x.startswith("G")]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes but I want to print Invoice number and its next string which is the Invoice number itself

Comment: So, try `re.findall(r'\b(?:{})\W+(\w+)'.format("|".join(patterns)), page_content)`

Comment: Check https://rextester.com/JTINET59478

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution is only printing the invoice number but I need it to be print like Invoice num : AAA092710SI

Comment: But there is only invoice number in the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if the below code helps:

```
str="Bank Details :\nBank Name\n:  Hdfc bank\nAccount No\n:  50200004915008\nAccount Name\n:  GNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nIFSC\n:  \nSr. \nNo.\nItem No.\nHSN Code\nArticle Code \nDescription\nColor\nTax %\nQuantity\nUnit Rate\nAmount\n1\nQCNBAG0035\n9\n84715000\nRefurbished DELL LATITUDE \nE7470 (CORE I7 6TH \nGEN/8GB/512GB \nSSD/WEBCAM/14'' TOUCH/WIN-\n10 HOME)\n18\n1\n28,813.56\n28,813.56\nOrder # \nQty Sum\n1\nTotal\n28,813.56\nDiscount Amount\n0\nCGST\n9%\n2593.22\nSGST\n9%\n2593.22\nNet Total\n34,000.00\nAmount in Words: ********* THIRTY FOUR THOUSAND RUPEES AND ZERO  PAISA ONLY \nBill To :\nShip To \nInvoice No.\n: PSIGHT1920000164\nEB Ghatkopar Store\nGMONEY PRIVATE LIMITED\nInvoice Date\n: 21/02/2020\nShop no.7, Raj Hans Helix 3, Shreyas \nCinema,\n1019, C WING, 215 ATRIUM\nPortal Order Id\n: \nLBS Road, Ghatkopar West\nNEXT TO COURTYARD MARRIOT, A.K.ROAD\nCust SA Code\n: \nMumbai\nANDHERI EAST, MUMBAI-400093\nCust Order No.\n: GMONEY PRIVATE \nLIMITED\nPlace of Supply: Maharashtra 400086\nMumbai  - 400093\nShipment Mode\n: \nState Code : 27\nState Code : \nStock Room\n: GHT-STR\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nG.S.T. No. : 27AAICG0467G1Z\nPayment Term\n: \nAWB\nPayment Due\n: 2/21/2020\nPartner Name\nShip to Contact\n: Yash\nTerms & Conditions :\n\nPayment by way of cheque/draft shall be in the name of company only. NEFT/RTGS favouring above bank details.Interest @24%per annum shall be \nlevied for delayed payment.\n\nBank charges of Rs.500/- plus GST per cheque shall be charged in case of dishonour of the cheque.\n\nThe courts at Mumbai only shall have the jurisdiction to entertain any dispute between the parties.\n\nWhether Tax is payable on Reverse Charge basis : No\nPage  1  of  1\nRegd Off. : Unit No. 415, Hubtown Solaris,N. S. Phadke Marg, Andheri East, Mumbai-400069\nTel No.: 022-61445600 TO 615 Fax No.: \nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nAuthorised Signatory\nTAX INVOICE\nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nRAJHANS, HELIX-3, L.B.S  ROAD\nGHATKOPAR WEST, MUMBAI\nMumbai  Maharashtra - 400086\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nState Code : 27\n"
s= str.replace(':','').split('\n')
for i,x in enumerate(s):
    if 'Invoice No' in x:
        print(x,s[i+1])

    if 'G.S.T. No.' in x:
        print(x)
```

Result:

```
Invoice No.  PSIGHT1920000164
G.S.T. No.  27AADCG6133E1ZV
G.S.T. No.  27AAICG0467G1Z
G.S.T. No.  27AADCG6133E1ZV
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution starting from the string you got after extracting text from the PDF:

```
s = "Bank Details :\nBank Name\n:  Hdfc bank\nAccount No\n:  50200004915008\nAccount Name\n:  GNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nIFSC\n:  \nSr. \nNo.\nItem No.\nHSN Code\nArticle Code \nDescription\nColor\nTax %\nQuantity\nUnit Rate\nAmount\n1\nQCNBAG0035\n9\n84715000\nRefurbished DELL LATITUDE \nE7470 (CORE I7 6TH \nGEN/8GB/512GB \nSSD/WEBCAM/14'' TOUCH/WIN-\n10 HOME)\n18\n1\n28,813.56\n28,813.56\nOrder # \nQty Sum\n1\nTotal\n28,813.56\nDiscount Amount\n0\nCGST\n9%\n2593.22\nSGST\n9%\n2593.22\nNet Total\n34,000.00\nAmount in Words: ********* THIRTY FOUR THOUSAND RUPEES AND ZERO  PAISA ONLY \nBill To :\nShip To \nInvoice No.\n: PSIGHT1920000164\nEB Ghatkopar Store\nGMONEY PRIVATE LIMITED\nInvoice Date\n: 21/02/2020\nShop no.7, Raj Hans Helix 3, Shreyas \nCinema,\n1019, C WING, 215 ATRIUM\nPortal Order Id\n: \nLBS Road, Ghatkopar West\nNEXT TO COURTYARD MARRIOT, A.K.ROAD\nCust SA Code\n: \nMumbai\nANDHERI EAST, MUMBAI-400093\nCust Order No.\n: GMONEY PRIVATE \nLIMITED\nPlace of Supply: Maharashtra 400086\nMumbai  - 400093\nShipment Mode\n: \nState Code : 27\nState Code : \nStock Room\n: GHT-STR\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nG.S.T. No. : 27AAICG0467G1Z\nPayment Term\n: \nAWB\nPayment Due\n: 2/21/2020\nPartner Name\nShip to Contact\n: Yash\nTerms & Conditions :\n\nPayment by way of cheque/draft shall be in the name of company only. NEFT/RTGS favouring above bank details.Interest @24%per annum shall be \nlevied for delayed payment.\n\nBank charges of Rs.500/- plus GST per cheque shall be charged in case of dishonour of the cheque.\n\nThe courts at Mumbai only shall have the jurisdiction to entertain any dispute between the parties.\n\nWhether Tax is payable on Reverse Charge basis : No\nPage  1  of  1\nRegd Off. : Unit No. 415, Hubtown Solaris,N. S. Phadke Marg, Andheri East, Mumbai-400069\nTel No.: 022-61445600 TO 615 Fax No.: \nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nAuthorised Signatory\nTAX INVOICE\nGNG Electronics Pvt Ltd\nRAJHANS, HELIX-3, L.B.S  ROAD\nGHATKOPAR WEST, MUMBAI\nMumbai  Maharashtra - 400086\nG.S.T. No. : 27AADCG6133E1ZV\nState Code : 27\n"

import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)
s = ''.join(ch for ch in s if ch not in exclude)

s = s.split("\n")
s = [v.strip() for v in s]

i = [i for i,v in enumerate(s) if "Invoice No" in v][0]

print(s[i] + ": " + s[i+1])
```

as you can see, the value of "Invoice No" is saved in `s[i+1]`.

Comment: its only working for printing Invoice No but if I need to print multiple values like Account Details, Invoice Date, Amount, Account No etc, it is not working